# Disable stretching time axis by additional tick (highcharts)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I wonder how to disable stretching time Axis by an additional tick in Highstock of Highcharts?
e.g. I have time-related data like this `{[timestamp, value],...}`, using **column series**. Data is grouped to months like this:

```
dataGrouping: {
   groupPixelWidth: 1,
   forced: true,
   units: [['month', [1]]]
}
```

And when showing data for a year range (January 2018 - December 2018), it shows also empty January 2019 at the end, what is needless.

Already have tried setting for the axis: `max, softMax, ceiling, endOnTick, maxPadding` and nothing of that helped.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/RostyslavP/49km6aLq/19/

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, Highcharts renders only what is in the series data, nothing more. Could you provide a minimal example of data that produces that problem ? Maybe it is a problem of local time conversion ? Isn't there a NULL value that is in the data for january 2019 ?

Comment: @JoffreySchmitz, for example, https://jsfiddle.net/RostyslavP/49km6aLq/19/

Comment: Do you want to show values in UTC or a specific timezone? Your issue is Highcharts is most likely defaulting to use UTC for the layout of the axises, but your moment function is using local time since it's called in the frontend. See https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.

Comment: @DanielVarela, Any timezone. This issue will still happen. The problem is not related to timezone. Highcharts adds padding to the end of the chart (`"this is useful when you don't want the highest data value to appear on the edge of the plot area"`). And seems that cannot be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts columns are equally placed on the plot area. Your data is the first and last day of the year, so when you want to show months perhaps it will be better to show the 1 Jan and 1 Dec 2019? Check the demo posted below.

```
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    data: [
      [
        startOfYear.valueOf(),
        150
      ],
      [
        endOfYear.valueOf() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        100
      ]
    ]
  }]
```

Demo:

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/546w1nrf/

Comment: That does not solve the issue. Data are presented for over the whole months from the start of 1st December to the end of 31st December.  That is why the data is grouped to months.